# How to order posts in Wordpress by date?

Tags: posts

How can I change re-order posts so that the most recent articles appear at the top of the list?

I found that this is possible by using something like this:

```
WP_Query('orderby=date&order=DESC')
```

But how and in which file should I use it?

I tried to add it at the end of in **wp-includes/post.php**, but it's breaking the site.

Comment: Just a warning: _Never edit core WordPress files_. Any custom code belongs in a plugin or theme. As to your question, posts are sorted this way by default. Where do you need to sort them?

Comment: On my Wordpress site the oldest posts appear at the top of the list and the most recent bellow them. I just need to reverse this so that the most recent posts appear at the top of the lis.

Comment: That would be very unusual. Which list? What theme are you using? Are you using any plugins that have anything to do with sorting posts?